Puppeteer with browser context opens an extra window windows
How can I add cookies to the default browser window/context, without opening a new window/context? (all pages should share cookies from the context)
For some reason, puppeteer seems to open two browser windows with this code. One with just one tab and it's about:blank. The other one starts with about:blank and redirects to the actually goes to the URL specified.
The only way I managed to only open one window is with doing page.setCookies right after puppeteer.launch without creating a new context, but that wont add cookies to the entire context.
System : Ubuntu 22.04,
Google Chrome for Testing   131.0.6778.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra')
const fs = require('fs');
const cookiesPath = "cookies.txt";
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const { createCursor } = require("ghost-cursor")
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())

 ...

 cookies = JSON.parse(cookies)

  let args = []
  if(proxy) {
    args.push(`--proxy-server=${proxy}`)
  }

  puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, args: args }).then(async browser => {
    const context = await browser.createBrowserContext()
    await context.setCookie(...cookies)

    let page = await context.newPage()
    let finalUserAgent = userAgent || defaultUserAgent
    console.log('Attempting to login w existing session..')
    await page.setUserAgent(finalUserAgent)
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(100000); // 90 seconds

  
    await page.goto(url)
    //await page.waitForTimeout(5000)
    //await browser.close()
    console.log(`logged in`)
  })
  console.log(userAgent, proxy);
  res.send("browser launched with session");

Any kind of help is much appreciated.

From the default window ("context"), you get a default tab ("page"), then opened a second window which also has a default tab. In the second window, you ignore the default tab and open a new one .newPage(). So everything is working as expected--I don't see any problem or point of confusion here. What is your question? I suggest providing a minimal, runnable example without distractions.

@ggorlen, I want to create a browser window with those cookies, and I want them to be for the entire browser context rather than a single page. Can you tell me how to do that without doing this?

Great, please ask that in the question with an [edit]. The cookies should be per-context, so can you explain how you came to believe that they're only per page? In other words, what evidence (ideally runnable code) shows you that cookies are per page?

yes with context.setCookies it adds the cookies to the entire context, but it also opens another window, (at least the way I do it do). The only way I managed to only open one window is with doing page.setCookies right after puppeteer.launch without creating a new context, but that wont add cookies to the entire context.

I see, so your question is how to add cookies to the default browser window/context, without opening a new window/context. You want one context, no blank pages, and all pages should share cookies from the context. Is that correct? If so, I suggest editing the question to state this (use a question mark to make it super clear what you're asking exactly).

done. If you can please add a way to do this as an answer.

Thanks. Did you trying using browser.defaultContext, browser.setCookie() and browser.pages()? The browser starts with a default context and a page in that context, so it's a matter of not calling createBrowserContext() and newPage(), which will open new windows and tabs, and using the existing stuff.
